# SharePoint Workflow does not sent notifications for task list assigned person?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have SharePoint 2013 Task list
I created on workflow when with stat when Item is created
I want and I set an email notifications when Item is created
I want to send email to assigned person
when I assign my self in task list add form I receive email notification
but when I assign other colleagues they don't receive email notification
I don't know what exactly is the problem.

Comment: Others have their email address included in the user profile?
btw is it a Visual studio WF or SP Designer workflow?

Comment: It is a SP Designer also not working and Nintex Workflow also not working

Comment: have you configured the user profile services properly? are you able to view your colleagues profile via the User profile service application in Central admin?